# RStudio: Save data from Viewer

Tags: r, rstudio

Due to a stupid mistake and a defective USB stick I lost a bunch of data and I am now trying to recover it.

Some of the the data is still displayed in the Viewer tabs when I open RStudio. However, I can only save R Scripts and R Markdownfiles out of the Viewer. The displayed data frames are nice and complete, I can sort and filter them in the Viewer, however, I cannot find a "save" option. Is there a possibility to save this displayed data into Rdata or csv or something similar?

Comment: Is the data visible when we run `ls()`?

Comment: It returns `character(0)`

Comment: Maybe copy paste?

Comment: Can you retrieve your code from the History and thereby recreate the data?

Comment: By "viewer" do you mean the Viewer tab? And, if that's what you mean, are you sorting/filtering a rendered `datatable` inside a rendered RMarkdown document? And, if that's what you mean, can you find the HTML file for that RMarkdown document? And, if you can do that, can you put that HTML document somewhere you can share it in a link?

Comment: If you right click on viewer window and click on "Open Frame", there is an option of print, not ideal maybe as PDF?

Comment: Have a look at @Jonathan's comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600153/save-view-output-of-rstudio-as-html).

Comment: @zx8754 I was thinking the same. There is an R package `pdftools` that has a function `pdf_text()` which can open the resulting PDF file and extract it to a regular text string (which would still need some manipulation to get back to a data frame, but should be doable).

Comment: In any event -- it is probably a good idea to print the data to a PDF file before trying other approaches. That way if worst comes to worst and you accidentally delete or damage the view you have a permanent record to fall back on.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest three different approaches, but none of them will necessarily work. I sort them according to my prior expectations of success.

1) You can copy all your data frame from the viewer and paste it into an external spreadsheet software to obtain a .csv file. E.g. through the "convert text to columns" button in MS Excel.
2) You can copy and paste the character string into an object that is passed to the `text` option of `read.table` or to `dput()`. Check out the "Copy your data" section of [this famous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)
3) Finally, you can get google Chrome's ["Inspect Element" function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120260/get-google-chromes-inspect-element-into-r) to inspect the `html` code of the object in the viewer. Once you find the table you can copy paste and scrape with an html parser, e.g. using the [`rvest` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf). Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks everybody, there is a way to access the data as Rdata files, which was kindly explained to me [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/218065947-Recover-data-from-Viewer-tabs)

I used the second method and located the files in `%localappdata%\RStudio-Desktop\viewer-cache`.